# Transform a dataframe in this specific way

Tags: pandas, dataframe

(Please help me to rephrase the title. I looked at questions with similar titles but they are not asking the same thing.)

I have a dataframe like this:

```
        A       B       C
0       1       4       7   
1       2       5       8   
2       3       6       9
```

(the first column is indexes and not important)

I need to transform it so it ends up like this:

```
A    A-1    A-2    B    B-1    B-2    C    C-1    C-2
1    2      3      4    5      6      7    8      9
```

I know about `DataFrame.T` which seems one step in the right direction, but how to programatically change the column headers, and move the rows "besides each other" to make it a single row?

Comment: First `pivot`, then flatten the MultiIndex (see question #11 in duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with convert values to one columns DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose, last flatten MultiIndex in list comprehension with `if-else` for expected ouput:

```
df1 = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df1.columns = [a if b == 0 else f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   A  A-1  A-2  B  B-1  B-2  C  C-1  C-2
0  1    2    3  4    5    6  7    8    9
```